# How to import Typescript file in Javascript file and interpret its contents before use?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am writing a Node app with Typescript but my Cucumber test is in Javascript. My question: If I have a Typescript file:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import checkCredentials from "./components/member/check-member-credentials";
import findMemberByEmail from "./components/member/find-member-by-email";

export default async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const memberByEmail = await findMemberByEmail(req.body.password);
  if (memberByEmail.error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "not found" });
  }

  const isMatch = await checkCredentials(
    memberByEmail.member.password,
    req.body.password,
  );
  if (isMatch) {
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "logged in" });
  }
  return res.status(401).json({ message: "not auth" });
};
```

And I am trying to import it in the context file of Cucumber test:

```
require('../../../../src/controllers/login.ts');
```

I get the typical js error:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I tried to use a library `typescript-require` and require it before my import (as in its docs):

```
require('typescript-require');
const login = require("../../../../src/controllers/login.ts");
```

But I'm still getting error:

```
> NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js test

src/controllers/components/member/check-member-credentials.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bcryptjs'.
src/controllers/components/member/check-member-credentials.ts(4,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/controllers/components/member/find-member-by-email.ts(1,16): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../db/models/index.js'.
src/controllers/components/member/find-member-by-email.ts(4,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/controllers/login-test.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.
src/controllers/login-test.ts(5,16): error TS1057: An async function or method must have a valid awaitable return type.
src/controllers/login-test.ts(11,25): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
src/controllers/login-test.ts(13,22): error TS1009: Trailing comma not allowed.
Fatal Error. Unable to compile TypeScript file. Exiting.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-basic-fit-v2@1.0.0 e2etest: `NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-basic-fit-v2@1.0.0 e2etest script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ali.atrash/.npm/_logs/2019-07-08T14_53_57_742Z-debug.log
```

Any other solution?

Comment: Compile first your `.ts` files to `.js` files. Then, execute the JS files.

Comment: @Paleo Yes I'm realising this! But I was hopping for a shortcut.

Comment: @Paleo not needed. According to [typescript-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-require)'s docs, TS files can be directly passed as inputs.

Comment: @LeeMoe please post a [mcve]

Comment: @NinoFiliu I edited my question and added all the error I get when I import my .ts file named 'login-test.ts'